# What is the benefit of using @Transactional in Controller layer on spring MVC application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-transactions

In an Spring 4 MVC application, i noticed that the `@Transactional` annotation was used in Controller layer. But in many places it was recommended to use within the service layer (service implementation class).

What is the benefit of using `@Transactional` in `@Controller` class?

Also, i have a service layer implementation class, which updates the data to database, i noticed the usage of Transaction properties as below

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
```

readOnly = true, was to be used when the method uses find or fetch some data from database. 
But using readOnly = true, the service layer was able to save the data anyways.
My application uses Spring 4 + Hibernate 4.2.20.

Transaction manager used by application

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" /> 
    </bean>
```

Using "`readOnly = true`" within the transaction will be able to save the data to database?

Comment: Are you sure that the data was correctly saved? If you use hibernate, and set a @Transaction to read-only, chances are, the writes won't happen, because it disable the statement flushing to the database (FlushMode is set to NEVER). But you won't have any error.

Comment: Some JDBC drivers ignore read-only mode.

Comment: True. Bottom line, the exact behavior of writes during read-only spring transactions is extremely dependent on the stack used, so you shouldn't rely on it. See this article for a more in-depth look on this issue https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ts1/

Comment: I never had issue with saving data using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use the annotation @Transactional in the @Controller.

There is a simple reason not to do this: best practice. A @Controller should not be aware of data persistence in a MVC logic, only the Service layer.

Also Spring recommends not to annotate whole classes only certain methods, this is also a good practice so you can mantain easily your application.